# Pass a list of user defined object from input field using spring form handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have an Employee class that looks like this.

```
public class Employee {

    private String Name;
    private List<Address> address;

    *****Getters and Setters****

}
```

And my Address class looks like this

```
public class Address {

    private int addressid;
    private Employee employee;

    @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
    private String description;

    *****Getters and Setters****

}
```

I want to bind List of addresses (Employee can have more than one address - 1:M) to the employee class with the data that is parsed through the form. Which looks like this.

I have 3 input address fields, one of the sample input fields look like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-3" for="exampleInputEmail1">Address
                                                    1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <form:input class="form-control" placeholder="" path="" />
            <form:errors path="" cssClass="error" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I have cut down many unnecessary form fields to demonstrate the problem more clearly. Please help me bind the list of input fields with the relevant class. Any advice for this design is also welcome.

Comment: do not format your description like codes,you make it difficult to read

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf for server side html rendering?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne no buddy no template engines...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thymeleaf` for this as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form|data</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="starter-template">
    <form th:action="@{employeeData}" method="post" th:object="${employee}">
        <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" th:name="name" name="name" placeholder="name" class="input u-one-third js-get-form-data"/>

        <th:block th:each="add,addStat:*{address}">
            <input th:field="*{address[__${addStat.index}__].description}" type="text" th:name="add.description" name="description" placeholder="description" class="input u-one-third js-get-form-data"/>

        </th:block>
        <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formData(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setDescription("TEST");
        address.setEmployee(employee);
        employee.getAddress().add(address);
        model.put("employee",employee);
       return "formData";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void employeeData(@Valid  Employee employeeData, BindingResult errors) {
     System.out.println(employeeData.getName());

    }
```

Please find the working commit [here](https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app/commit/21cc23adc2d94af463cbd6e94d635b98531a6a46).

Comment: thanks i found a way to work around my requirements. appreciate your help. thanks